# Exponential equation problem, where bases are not the same.

Tags: exponential-function

$(3/4)^{2x-1}= (4/3)^{x-2}$

How do i get the bases to be the same? My teacher just added a $-1$ and everything magically turned to
$(3/4)^{2-x}$, How did this happen?

Comment: $(4/3)=(3/4)^{-1}$

Comment: $(4/3)^x=(3/4)^{-x}$ because $4/3=(3/4)^{-1}$.

Comment: Why did the 2 become positive?

Comment: Because $-(x-2)=2-x$

Comment: Thank you very much! You dont know how much this helped!

Answer (score 0):

$(3/4)^{2x-1}= (4/3)^{x-2}$ and then as Tito mentioned we have $(3/4)^{2x-1}= (3/4)^{-x+2} $
so they have the same base and we should solve the equation for powers:
$2x-1=-x+2$ and then $3x = +3$ so $x=1$.